# How can I add a Freshdesk widget during runtime in Angular?

Tags: angular, freshdesk

I'm using Angular 9 and am trying to add a Freshdesk widget to my app. The snippet for that widget that looks like this:

```
<script>
window.fwSettings={
'widget_id': <MY PERSONAL ID>,
'locale': 'en'
};
!function(){if("function"!=typeof window.FreshworksWidget){var n=function(){n.q.push(arguments)};n.q=[],window.FreshworksWidget=n}}()
```

If I add the snippet directly into my `index.html` file it works fine but I want to be able to programatically set the `locale` property to whatever language the current user has chosen.

That means this snippet needs to be added during runtime, but I have no idea how to it in Angular.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may get more help at Freshdesk [official developer community](https://community.developers.freshworks.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. In my `app.component.ts` I put the snippet in a function after I've loaded my apps locale:

```
loadFreshDesk(locale): void {
   window.fwSettings = {
      widget_id: MY_WIDGET_ID,
      locale: MY_FRESH_DESK_LOCALE,
    };

    !(function () {
      if ('function' !== typeof window.FreshworksWidget) {
        const n = function () {
          n.q.push(arguments);
        };
        (n.q = []), (window.FreshworksWidget = n);
      }
    })();
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/MY_WIDGET_ID.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: its wrong you can not add this code in .ts file like this. also how can you show widget?
there is npm package available for this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-freshdesk-webwidget